# How to assure that some type has a specific member

Tags: scala

I am searching for a way to restrict my polymorphic class to types that have a certain member function.

```
class Table[T](bla: Array[T]) {
  val symbols = bla

  symbols.foreach( x => x * probability(x))

  def probability(t: T) : Double =  ...
}
```

This code does not compile because T doesnt have member *. How can I assure this. I dont want to use inheritance.

Edit: probability is actually implemented. It returns a Double.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please fix your code? What is the missing member, where does it appear in the code, is there a probability method in Table and what is is signature?

Comment: Thx for the remark. The missing member is: * .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved in different ways. For example, if you just want type `T` to have some method (and you don't care whether this method defined on the object or there is implicit conversion that coverts object to something that has this method), then you can use *view bounds*. Here is an example that expects type `T` to have method `def *(times: Int): T`:

```
class Table[T <% {def *(times: Int): T}](bla: Array[T]) {
  bla.foreach( x => println(x * 2))
} 

new Table(Array("Hello", "World"))
// Prints:
//   HelloHello
//   WorldWorld
```

`String` does not have method `*`, but there exist an implicit conversion to [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html) that has this method.

Here is another example. In this case I restricting type `T` with method `def size: Int`:

```
class Table[T <% {def size: Int}](bla: Array[T]) {
  bla.foreach( x => println(x.size))
} 

new Table(Array(List(1, 2, 3), List("World")))
// Prints:
//  3
//  1
```

`List` has method `size`, and it also works as expected.

But this could be more involving if you are working with numeric values like ints, floats, doubles, etc. In this case I can recommend you to use *context bound*. Scala has [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) type class. You can use it to work with numbers without knowledge about their type (with `Numeric` you can actually work with anything that can be represented as number, so your code would be much more general and abstract). Here is an example if it:

```
import math.Numeric.Implicits._

class Table[T : Numeric](bla: Array[T]) {
  bla.foreach( x => println(x * x))
} 

new Table(Array(1, 2, 3))
// Prints:
//  1
//  4
//  9

new Table(Array(BigInt("13473264523654723574623"), BigInt("5786785634377457457465784685683746583454545454")))
// Prints:
//  181528856924372945350108280958825119049592129
//  33486887978237312740760811863500355048015109407078304275771413678604907671187978933752066116
```

---

#### Update

As you noted in comments, `Numeric` still does not solve your problem, because it can only work on the numbers of the same type. You can simply solve this problem by introducing new type class. Here is an example of it:

```
import math.Numeric.Implicits._

trait Convert[From, To] {
    def convert(f: From): To
}

object Convert {
    implicit object DoubleToInt extends Convert[Double, Int] {
        def convert(d: Double): Int = d.toInt
    }

    implicit object DoubleToBigInt extends Convert[Double, BigInt] {
        def convert(d: Double): BigInt = d.toLong
    }
}

type DoubleConvert[To] = Convert[Double, To]

class Table[T : Numeric : DoubleConvert](bla: Array[T]) {
  bla.foreach( x => println(x * implicitly[DoubleConvert[T]].convert(probability(x))))
  def probability(t: T) : Double = t.toDouble + 2.5
} 

new Table(Array(1, 2, 3))
new Table(Array(BigInt("13473264523654723574623"), BigInt("5786785634377453434")))
```

With `DoubleConvert` type class and `T : Numeric : DoubleConvert` context bound you are not only saying, that `T` should be some kind of number, but also that there should exist some evidence, that it can be converted from `Double`. You are receiving such evidence with `implicitly[DoubleConvert[T]]` and then you are using it to convert `Double` to `T`. I defined `Convert` for Double -> Int and Double -> BigInt, but you can also define you own for the types you need.

Comment: Thanks for your effor but this only works for: x * x. It doesnt work for x * probability(x) where probablity return a Double. So it seems it works is * get arguments of the same type.

Comment: @peri4n: Yes, you are right. `Numeric` will only work with the objects of the same type. But in order to assist you further I need to know more detail about how and what you are trying to archive. It would be nice to see implementation of `probability`. Is it possible to implement it using only methods available in `Numeric`? BTW, You can also be more precise and use either `Integral` or `Fractional` type classes. They have even more methods. There are also other solutions (still using `Numeric`) to this problem, but, I need more information about it.

Comment: @peri4n: I updated my answer with simple solution to the problem you described, but still I think it would be nice to check, whether it possible to implement `probability` using `Numeric` only.

Answer (score 1):

Use scala's structural typing: http://markthomas.info/blog/?p=66

Your code will end up looking something like this:

```
class Table[T <: {def *(i:Int): T}](bla: Array[T]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That won't work...
`scala> class Table[T <: {def *}](bla:Array[T]) {}
defined class Table

scala> new Table[Int](Array(1,2,4))
<console>:8: error: type arguments [Int] do not conform to class Table's type pa
rameter bounds [T <: AnyRef{def *: Unit}]
       val res0 =
           ^
<console>:9: error: type arguments [Int] do not conform to class Table's type pa
rameter bounds [T <: AnyRef{def *: Unit}]
       new Table[Int](Array(1,2,4))`

Comment: I downvoted because it won't do what the OP wants and I don't see how it can be made to do what the OP wants.

Comment: @Kim Stebel: Really. The OP question says that the compiler is complaining that T doesn't have a member function. With structural typing, you can require that a type have a particular function without using inheritance a la duck typing. My code isn't compiler worthy, but so what?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else is answering with "Structural Types".  Quite rightly so, because that's the correct answer!

Instead of repeating the obvious, I'll expand upon it.  Taking a snippet from Easy Angel's reply:

```
class Table[T <% {def *(times: Int): T}](bla: Array[T]) {
  bla foreach {x => println(x*2)}
}
```

If you find you're using the same expression `{def *(times: Int): T}` more than once, then you can create a type alias for it

```
type HasTimes = {def *(times: Int): T}

class Table[T <% HasTimes](bla: Array[T]) {
  bla foreach {x => println(x*2)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use inheritance, the only other restriction you can apply is a context bound. So if you have a list of classes that are okay, you create an `implicit object HasStar[X]` for each class X and use a context bound like `T:HasStar`. I know this probably isn't exactly what you want, but I don't think there are any better options.